# Getting the name of a named cell in MS Excel 2011

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

I am using a formula in Excel, which involves cell names.
The formula is

```
=MIN(name1,name2,name3)
```

name1 is the smallest, but it shows name1's **value**. I want it to show the text "Name1". How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

With *Name1* assigned to **A1**, *Name2* assigned to **B7** and *Name3* assigned to **C11**, the formula:

```
=MIN(Name1,Name2,Name3)
```

returns the value of the minimum:

[image]

The following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function WhereIs(v As Variant, r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range)
   If v = r1.Value Then WhereIs = r1.Name.Name
   If v = r2.Value Then WhereIs = r2.Name.Name
   If v = r3.Value Then WhereIs = r3.Name.Name
End Function
```

will return the Name of the cell containing that minimum:

[image]